# ldapUser corresponds to which filed in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the below code to find the user in the active directory

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = null;
using (dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, ldapUser, ldapPassword))
{
    try
    {
        Object adsiObject = dirEntry.NativeObject;
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        errorInfo.ErrorCode = -1;
        errorInfo.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
    }
}
```

I have a doubt about "ldapUser".

Which field does it correspond in the Active Directory ?
Is it "user logon name" or "user logon name pre-2000" ?

And i need to know the no of characters that could be given for "ldapUser" field.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "User Logon Name" is in reality the ***User Principal Name*** (UPN) and the pre-Windows 2000 is the ***sAMAccountName***. You can find both in the Attribute Editor (you need the advanced features for that).

The property that is edited with `dirEntry.Username` is the sAMAccountName.

I advice you to edit your UPN too if you change the username. I prefer directly using the properties of the `DirectoryEntry` object like that :

```
dirEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = newName_;
dirEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = newName_ + "@yourdomain.com";
```

About the characters needed number, it depends of your GPO (for the minimal value and if special/capital characters are required or not).
For the maximum value, it's 20 characters. I faced to this issue few month ago.

Hope that helped.